# Zabbix Agent unable to read /var/log/messages

Tags: permissions, zabbix, logserver

So I am trying to monitor the logs of a VM running Centos 7. Specifically the one giving problems is /var/log/messages. I have changed both the group ownership of the file ( made the pertaining change in logrotate.conf ) and manually on the already created file. Below you can see the permissions of it :

```
[matias@Centos_7_VM ~]$ sudo ls -lh /var/log/messages
-rw-rwx---+ 1 root zabbix 889K jul 25 10:53 /var/log/messages
[matias@Centos_7_VM ~]$ getfacl /var/log/messages
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/log/messages
# owner: root
# group: zabbix
user::rw-
user:zabbix:rwx
group::---
mask::rwx
other::---
```

But even with all of those changes, the zabbix agent is getting permission denied to read that log. Is there something else blocking that process from reading the file?

#### Agent log

```
993:20180725:062459.211 Starting Zabbix Agent [Centos_7_VM]. Zabbix 3.2.11 (revision 76339).
   993:20180725:062459.256 **** Enabled features ****
   993:20180725:062459.257 IPv6 support:          YES
   993:20180725:062459.257 TLS support:           YES
   993:20180725:062459.257 **************************
   993:20180725:062459.257 using configuration file: /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf
   993:20180725:062459.303 agent #0 started [main process]
   999:20180725:062459.359 agent #1 started [collector]
  1003:20180725:062459.396 agent #2 started [listener #1]
  1004:20180725:062459.406 agent #3 started [listener #2]
  1005:20180725:062459.413 agent #4 started [listener #3]
  1007:20180725:062459.472 agent #5 started [active checks #1]
  1007:20180725:105103.700 active check "log[/var/log/messages,(?i)error]" is not supported: Cannot open file "/var/log/messages": [13] Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called SELinux.

Unfortunately the SELinux policy for the Zabbix agent is not well developed (yet) and almost anything you might want to monitor is going to be denied. I personally set the Zabbix agent type to permissive to work around this. This lets the Zabbix agent essentially bypass SELinux while it still applies to everything else on the system.

```
semanage permissive -a zabbix_agent_t
```

Comment: It worked flawlessly Micheal. Just one question, why the "_t" at the end of the command?

Comment: Because the name of the SELinux type is `zabbix_agent_t`.

Comment: @MatiasBarrios To be overly clear, the `_t` suffix in SELinux means type. You'll find that there are three suffixes like this: `_u` for User, `_r` for Role and `_t` for type.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer not to disable SELinux in any way:

You could check if it's SELinux by running `audit2allow -a` and check if there is any output which includes Zabbix. Also you could simply set permissive mode temporarily to verify the blockage:

1. `sudo setenforce 0`
2. Check if zabbix agent can do its thing
3. `sudo setenforce 1`

If it really is SELinux denying the agent, try the following:

Create a policy to allow whatever is denying Zabbix (as root or sudo):

```
grep zabbix /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M myzabbix
```

This will pipe any Zabbix denials into audit2allow which creates a policy file and compiled binary in the directory that you are in. I usually do this in `/root/selinux` for cleanliness.

Then run `semodule -i myzabbix.pp`

This loads the policy into SELinux and it is permanent so no need to worry about reboots reversing policy.